# Block All DNS servers except specific one (whitelist)

Tags: domain-name-system, cisco, router, access-control-list

I currently a have a CISCO router and I would like to configure an ACL that will allow only Google DNS servers and block all others if they're configured on the client.

I have the following ACL however it's no applying correctly and it allows other DNS servers to be used instead of Google.

ACLS

```
access-list 101 permit udp any host 8.8.8.8 eq 53
access-list 101 permit udp any host 8.8.4.4 eq 53
access-list 101 deny udp any any eq 53
access-list 101 permit ip any any
```

Is there anything that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you paste the interface config which you applied this ACL? And how did you test other DNS is working?

Answer (score 2):

You defined your ACL, however you don't show to which interfaces you applied it to. ACL without applying it to interface has no effect. Refer to

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/ios-firewall/23602-confaccesslists.html#applyacls

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/sec_data_acl/configuration/15-sy/sec-data-acl-15-sy-book/sec-create-ip-apply.html#GUID-30BB74FC-ABE4-43B6-9D49-7A78CFF024B9

Basically you want to

```
interface ethernet 0
 ip access-group 101 out
```

Replace your ethernet 0 with your interface type and number.

Comment: Actually, as an extended ACL, you want to apply it as close to the source as possible. That would be inbound on the LAN interface. Applying it outbound on the WAN interface forces the router to route packets that are destined to be dropped, wasting router resources. The general rule is that standard ACLs get placed as close to the destination as possible in order to not block too much traffic, and extended ACLs get placed as close to the source as possible to prevent unnecessary routing.

Answer (score 1):

Your access list should be applied inbound on the LAN interface(s). It is an extended ACL that should be applied as close to the source as possible. It should look something like:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 description LAN interface
 ip access-group 101 in
```

You also have a problem in that you are only blocking DNS over UDP, while DNS must also support TCP. [*RFC 5966, DNS Transport over TCP - Implementation Requirements*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5966) clarifies the fact that DNS must support TCP:

> This document therefore updates the core DNS protocol specifications
> such that support for TCP is henceforth a REQUIRED part of a full DNS
> protocol implementation.

You probably want something like this:

```
access-list 101 permit udp any host 8.8.8.8 eq 53
access-list 101 permit udp any host 8.8.4.4 eq 53
access-list 101 deny udp any any eq 53
access-list 101 permit tcp any host 8.8.8.8 eq 53
access-list 101 permit tcp any host 8.8.4.4 eq 53
access-list 101 deny tcp any any eq 53
access-list 101 permit ip any any
```

Placing the above ACL inbound to the router from the LAN will block any DNS requests from entering the router unless they are destined for `8.8.8.8` or `8.8.4.4`.